# Finding closest aggregated value using Knapsack or foreach

Tags: php, algorithm

I am looking for the simplest solution for my problem that would also be most time efficient on the server.

I have a value I have to approach to as close as possible, with minimum of items being summed together.

I have the values stored in a multidimensional array of values, which are smaller then the value I am looking for.

Solution nr.1 I could sort, send through foreach sentance and then get first and last value and then sum them and if they are too big, then use the next biggest value, if they are too small I could use the next smallest.

Or I could try some sort of Knapsack implementation that would get me the least amount of items used.

Any suggestions on what would be better? Or am I missing some solution?

```
    $example = array(
    [0]=>([val]=>'1684'),
    [1]=>([val]=>'2759'),
    [2]=>([val]=>'3997'),
    [3]=>([val]=>'8543'),
    [4]=>([val]=>'9534'),
    [5]=>([val]=>'957'),);
```

This is the example of the array, now I would want to get value closest to 13000. What would be the most time efficient path to take for that if I had betweek 10 and 250 results per array

Comment: May be you stated your problem correctly, but with statements only, it's un-clear to others. Please put some sample input data+code you tried+output you got from your code+desired output you want actually.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem. That's exactly what you are describing.